# Powershell script to check TLS 1.2 enabled in browser

Tags: powershell, browser, scripting, tls1.2, powershell-4.0

I can have a script to check tls 1.2 enabled in registry in following locations.

•   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\DisabledByDefault is present, the value should be 0.

•   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\Enabled is present, value should be 1.

https://support.site24x7.com/portal/en/kb/articles/how-to-check-if-tls-1-2-is-enabled

```
$path = @(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\Enabled)  -and @(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\DisabledByDefault)  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($null -eq $path) {  # Always place $null on the LHS
  'not found' 
}
```

How can i check TLS 1.2 enabled in browser (not in registry) using powershell script?

Comment: you'll need to figure out the respective registry key for that browser setting.  Unfortunately I suspect that may be a per user setting which makes things a lot trickier.  While you can check reg keys in HKCU it will be your registry and HKU will be populated with only users that are logged in.  It just makes things quite complicated but not impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check the schannel keys in your question, this works

```
$key = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\'
if (Test-Path $key) {
  $TLS12 = Get-ItemProperty $key
  if ($TLS12.DisabledByDefault -ne 0 -or $TLS12.Enabled -eq 0) {
    Throw "TLS 1.2 Not Enabled"
  }
}
```

Note that most browsers also check the `SecureProtocols` value in Internet Settings, which can be set per-user or for the whole machine:

```sh
# User settings
Get-ItemProperty 'hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -Name SecureProtocols
# Machine settings
Get-ItemProperty 'hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -Name SecureProtocols
```

The `Value` is a little strange since it is a combination of the hex-values for each supported protocol. For example, TLS1.2 is `0x800` or `2048`. Check out the [Microsoft TLS 1.2 page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392) for more details on all this information.

It is showing 280 tls 1.2 off,tls 1.2 a80 On in my laptop registry.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, it really helpful. Can you also mention the full path for internet settings ?  is is Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Protocols  what should be the key value, is it same as before?

Comment: @SmartestVEGA I've updated my answer. Unfortunately not, the correct value is more complex than just `0`or`1`. Please check out the linked page for more information.

Comment: Thank you, i got the values in my system as 280 off,a80 On. Great thanks for your help

Answer (score 8):

When running in the PowerShell_ISE, the .Net Class Property is a simple method to query TLS settings:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
```

If TLS is only enabled the output will be:

> Ssl, Tls

If TLS1.2 is enabled then the list will be:

> Tls, Tls11, Tls12

However, the return type is a System.Enum, which can be checked using a regular expression as follows:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -match "Tls12"
```

Resulting in a boolean result

Comment: This is only telling what protocols dot net will attempt to negotiate, but it is still subject to the server configuration. So, dot net could tell you Tls12 in the ServicePointManager, but if it is disabled on the server dot net will revert to the next highest protocol.